# PiCamera V2 NoIR and AMG8833 thermal sensor mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC

Tags: python, pi-4, opencv, picamera, troubleshooting

Hardware used: Raspberry pi 4b, 4 gb ram, AMG8833 thermal camera, PiCamera V2 noir, ALL brand new, i just bought them few weeks ago.

Im trying to do finish a project and i ran into a not that good error, i couldnt find anything on the internet till now!

[image: This is the main code that i m trying to use and ther eis the errors that i get.]

[image: This is the PiCamera simple code.]

[image: Blob detection code that is super ok, it works but it uses the image from the picamera]

If the picamera does not get a capture the blob detection algorithm gets the same image from the last time... and it s not that nice.

And the AMG8833 code is the adafruit version that i changed with a simple while (1) loop so it can run and update continuously.

Ok, the question is: Why do i keep getting that error only when it is in main code and when i test it in the normal folder i wont get any error and it works perfectly?

I tried with a while loop and it gives me the same error and then i tried a simple version and it worked.
Same in the main code - i used it in the while 1 loop and it gives me the error from the first image and then i deleted it from the while loop and dropped it outside the while loop and the problem seems to be from the while loop, but i still dont know yet... what is the problem.

I would like to see some answers from more experienced guys, i only have like... 2 weeks in programming and raspberry pi..

HELP!!!

Comment: Please don't post your code as pictures. Post it in a CODE block as plain text (with appropriate formatting if it's python).

Comment: Ok, sorry, i didnt know how to use it for the first time.. Thank you for your advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: FOR anyone that is in need for this information]

just add camera.close() method at the final of this program and it should work, because you use 2 cameras, AMG8833 and PiCamera, you cand use only one at a time, thats why you have to close the process! Good day!

Comment: AFAICT the problem was actually that you keep initialising the pi camera on every call; not the fact that you are using 2 sensors. Normally you would only call `camera=PiCamera()` once. ENOSPC seems to confirm that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How should the code look like so it wont call it multiple times?